# I'm trying to convert a .py file into .exe file by pyinstaller but this warning showed up

Tags: python, warnings, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert a .py file into a .exe file using `pyinstaller` but I got this warning:

```
WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer.exe, pyi-bindepend.exe, pyi-grab_version.exe, pyi-makespec.exe, pyi-set_version.exe and pyinstaller.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\kundan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is very descriptive, although you can ignore it but for your comfort its better to add them to PATH.

Why? so you can directly use pyinstaller in cmd (and other mentioned .exe files).

How? Add this folder to path `C:\Users\kundan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts`
https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html

https://bsoyka.medium.com/adding-files-to-the-path-on-windows-10-4fbb4295c549

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall python. In installer check `Add python.exe to PATH` checkbox